# for i,j in a,b: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, data-structures

```py
def missing_array(a,b):
    a=a.sort()
    b=b.sort()

    for i,j in a,b:
        if i!=j:
            return i

    return a[-1]
```

`missing_array([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,4,5,6])`

WHY I AM GETTING THIS ERROR

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7c1f70dbb9ae> in <module>
      9     return a[-1]
     10 
---> 11 missing_array([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,4,5,6])
     12 

<ipython-input-3-7c1f70dbb9ae> in missing_array(a, b)
      3     b=b.sort()
      4 
----> 5     for i,j in a,b:
      6         if i!=j:
      7             return i

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

​

Comment: The `.sort()` method on lists *doesn't return anything* - it doesn't need to, you obviously already had the list in order to call the sort method on it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `.sort()` returns `None`. In your case `a=a.sort();b=b.sort()` `a` ,`b` are assigned to `None`. If you dont want to sort the list in place try using `sorted()`.

Answer (score 0):

From [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) :

> Python lists have a built-in list.sort() method that modifies the list in-place.

In-place signifies that calling this method will sort the list object on which you call the method, and will NOT return a new list. The sort() method has no return type (void method); in Python, such methods still return a 'None'.

Also, your syntax for iterating through the two arrays is invalid. You should consider the 'zip' method, which, according to [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip),

> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

So your code should be:

```
def missing_array(a,b):
    a.sort()
    b.sort()
    # Iterating over iterator of tuples returned by zip:
    for (i,j) in zip(a,b):
        if i!=j:
            return i
    return a[-1] if len(a) > len(b) else b[-1]

print(missing_array([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,4,5,6]))
```